# Python Webbrowser HTTP Headers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question if there is a way of changing the HTTP Header of python webbrowser.
How can I change the header information before opening the url
webbrowser.open_new(url)

is this possible

Comment: I don't think so. It simply lets the default browser do its default thing, it doesn't make the request itself and thereby has no influence on it.

Comment: i see thanks sir/mam :)